# each function is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

1.this line is working

```
alert( $('<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>').find('div[title="People Picker"]'));
```

2.but below block is not working

```
$('<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>').find('div[title="People Picker"]').each(function (){              
alert('hi');
});
```

3.this is also working

```
$('div[title="People Picker"]').each(function () {
alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: stick to the working ones then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From quick looking at your code you forgot the `#` sign which represents `ID` :

`$('#<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>')`

Comment: The problem was with # 
previously i was doing with javascript and now with jquery we need to add #
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try alerting the length of the matched elements:

```
alert($('<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>').find('div[title="People Picker"]').length);
```

If it's 0 then you matched nothing. If you find the elements but did not find them as descendants of the `$('<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>')` selector then they are either not part of that child DOM or your selector is wrong, which seems to be the case as you have no `#` for ID selector.

Comment: `'<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>')` is not valid. he just forgot the # sign.

Comment: We doesn't know what returns `<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>` . If it whole numbers it also not good.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes that is the case. I just wanted to list the possibilities to make the answer more complete :)

Comment: @jQuery00 ClientID will return the ID without the prefix.

Comment: I got the solution $('<%=singleUserPP.ClientID%>') it was returning different object not what i was expected and of course .length is 0 
also i forgot # before id.
thank you all :)